# xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 1] = dt.Rows[i].Field("EmpName");

Tags: c#

the error is Error  4   The type arguments for method 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(System.Data.DataRow, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is saying that this line of code doesn't provide enough type information context to infer at compile time the type argument [for `DataRowExtensions.Field<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx):

```
xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 1] = dt.Rows[i].Field("EmpName");
```

This is probably because the assignment to `xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 1]` could, technically, be any number of things.  (I'm not familiar with what that is, so can't really be more specific.)

In that case, you'd simply have to specify the type parameter explicitly.  For example, I would expect something called `EmpName` to be a `string`, so:

```
xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 1] = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("EmpName");
```